# flexdashboard layout with tabset

Tags: r, flexdashboard

how do I get such a layout in flexdashboard?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know a lot of webdev, this isn't really possible with flexdashboard, but what you could do is have each tabbed sections with the box next to it, and then separate them by pages in Flexdashboard

````
---
title: "Tabset Column"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---


Section
===========================================================

Column {.tabset}
-------------------------------------
    
### Chart 1
    
```{r}
```
### Chart 3
    
```{r}
```
   
Column 
-------------------------------------
   
### Chart 2

```{r}
```   

Section 2
===========================================================

Column {.tabset}
-------------------------------------
    
### Chart 1
    
```{r}
```
### Chart 3
    
```{r}
```
   
Column 
-------------------------------------
   
### Chart 2

```{r}
```
````

Which gives me a similar layout, not exactly as you wanted, this may be possible with Shiny code.

[image]